# django, simple quote on a queryset

Tags: django, django-queryset

I want to make a query on a model what contains some simple quote :

```
Operation.objects.exclude(field__icontains="'foobar'")
```

But it does not work.

Comment: You haven't explained *what* doesn't work.

Comment: The queryset contains some objects with values 'foobar' for the field "field"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the \ to escape the ' char

```
Operation.objects.exclude(field__icontains="\'foobar\'")
```

in python:

```
>>> a = "\'hi\'"
>>> print a
'hi'
```

Comment: No, I have some objects Operation who contains the value 'foobar'

Comment: @Py: Did you try Samuele solutions before posting your comment?